# Get all roles from AD LDS Programmatically

Tags: .net, active-directory, adlds

I am looking for some guidance on how I can connect to AD LDS programmatically. I am trying to retrieve all AD LDS roles using a C# program.

Any pointers on where to get started will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732460%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), AD LDS roles are AD groups that reside in the `CN=Roles` container of your LDS instance - right?

With the classes in the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace, you can get those groups pretty easily:

```
// set up the "ApplicationDirectory" context and use the "CN=Roles" container
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, "ldsserver:389", "CN=Roles,DC=YourCompany,DC=com");

// set up a "QBE" group principal
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" should be "GroupPrincipal" types only
}
```

Read all about the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD (and AD LDS)!